# Script to modify Local Group Policy Editor?(internet setting autocomplete)

Tags: internet-explorer, autocomplete, registry, inno-setup, group-policy

I am trying to automate the turn off all AutoComplete Internet Settings in Local Group Policy Editor by scripting in innosetup. The idea is that it would modify the computer/server so that the user doesn't have to do these steps manually.

[Local Group Policy Editor] -> User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Internet Explorer Maintenance -> Advanced (after clicking on preference mode in previous step) -> Uncheck everything in the “AutoComplete” section

I had tried to modify these keys

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
>      "UseFormSuggest"="no"
>      "FormSuggest Passwords"="no"
>     "FormSuggest PW Ask"="no"
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
>      "Append Completion"="no"
>      "Use AutoComplete"="no"
>      "AutoSuggest"="no"

But then after had done so, I went back to Local Group Policy Editor, these boxes were still checked. 
So I wonder if there's any other way to do this beside modifying registry keys or am I even doing this the right way, or missing key,.etc...?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 (haven't tested any other versions) I noticed that either enabling or disabling the setting "Disable AutoComplete for forms" in the Local Group Policy Editor will create two registry values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`:

- `Use FormSuggest`
- `UseFormSuggest`

However, if you reset it to "Not configured" only the first one (the one with the space between "Use" and "FormSuggest" will be removed. Apart from this strange behaviour I can confirm that disabling these three (or four) settings will prevent IE to suggest or ask for saving passwords.

- `"Use FormSuggest"="no"`
- `"UseFormSuggest"="no"`
- `"FormSuggest Passwords"="no"`
- `"FormSuggest PW Ask"="no"`

**NOTE**

It also works in a WPF WebView. Make sure you restart your Group Policy Snap-In. I also had to close IE and restart it for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a "swiss army knife" for Local Group Policy stuff. It's called LOCALGPO and it's part of the download from Microsoft Security Compliance Manager (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677002.aspx).

While there is some guidence on how to use the tool here and here, I cover it thoroughly in my Group Policy book which can be found here: http://www.gpanswers.com/book

Its in Appendix B.

I also cover it in my GPTraining Class (www.Gpanswers.com/training) if you need more of a boost.

Hope the LocalGPO tool helps you out.

-Jeremy Moskowitz, Group Policy MVP

Comment: This "swiss army knife" can only backup and restore, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

I have used [LGPO.exe tool](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/) and it worked:

1. Export policy to text file using LGPO.exe
2. Edit the text file
3. Load the text file using LGPO.exe